# Importing main .tex file into lyx

Tags: latex, lyx

I'm trying to import into lyx some .tex documents that use theorem environment (ntheorem package).
When i tried to use **file/import** i get the following issues
Error when execution tex2lyx -fixedenc utf8 -f "main.tex" "main.lyx"

Comment: LyX tries its best to convert (what could be arbitrary and complicated) content into something it recognises. It fails because *something* couldn't be converted. Without seeing the code, it's not possible to help you.

Comment: Probably similar to http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10432